# SQL Update query - trying to update sql record

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, sql-update

I am trying to update SQL table record. I have written program using java to upload file(s) (with any extension) into SQL database table and while storing file I have stored file path in SQL table. These uploaded files store into "allfiles" folder in local system and in SQL table path column shows file path as "allfiles\". Now, I have also written program to update that record "update.jsp" but update query is not updating SQL record for that id. Please suggest me where I am getting wrong. Below is the code. No error occurred.

In short : I want when user update any record then user click on "Edit" button and then jsp page will open with values fetched and if user want to modify file also then he/she will select file from local system and click on "update" button then record should be updated with changes and newly selected file should store into SQL table.

filelist.jsp fetch all records from database table.

**filelist.jsp**

```html
<tr>
<th style="width: 20%">File ID</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Z ID</th>
<th style="width: 20%">First Name</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Last Name</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Mail ID</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Division</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Department</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Cost Center Code</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Document No.</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Document Name</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Document Type</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Document Category</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Document Classification</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Authorised By</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Validity - From Date</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Validity - To Date</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Document Level</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Document General(F31151)</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Serial No.</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Revision No.</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Issuer</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Status</th>
<th style="width: 20%">File Name</th>
<th style="width: 20%">File Path</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Added Date</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Download</th>
<th class="text-center">Action</th>
<th style="width: 20%">Delete File</th>
</tr>
<%
  Connection con = null;
  PreparedStatement ps = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  String id = request.getParameter("id");
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms","root","");
  String zid = request.getParameter("zid");
  String sql = "select * from dmsfiles where zid= '"+zid+"'";
  ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
  rs = ps.executeQuery();
  while(rs.next()){
  //String id = rs.getString("id");
%>
<tr>
<td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>              
<td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>           
<td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>   
<td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td> 
<td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td> 
<td><%=rs.getString(6)%></td> 
<td><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(8)%></td>              
<td><%=rs.getString(9)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(10)%></td>          
<td><%=rs.getString(11)%></td> 
<td><%=rs.getString(12)%></td>           
<td><%=rs.getString(13)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(14)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(15)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(16)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(17)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(18)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(19)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(20)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(21)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(22)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(23)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(24)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(25)%></td>        
<td><a href="DownloadServletClass?fileName=<%=rs.getString(23)%>" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a></td>
<td><a href="update.jsp?id=<%=rs.getString("id")%>" class="btn btn-warning">Update</a></td>
<td><a href="deleteFile.jsp?id=<%=id%>" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?')">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<%
}
 %>
```

**This is update.jsp**

```html
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<%
try{
String id = request.getParameter("id");
String z_id = request.getParameter("zid");
String first_Name = request.getParameter("firstname");
String last_Name = request.getParameter("lastname");
String mail_i_d = request.getParameter("mailid");
String d_iv = request.getParameter("division");
String de_pt = request.getParameter("department");
String cost_centercode = request.getParameter("costcentercode");
String doc_num = request.getParameter("documentnumber");     
String doc_Name = request.getParameter("documentname");
String doc_Type = request.getParameter("Document_Type");     String doc_Category = request.getParameter("Document_Category");   
String doc_classification = request.getParameter("Document_Classification");
String authorised_by = request.getParameter("authorisedby");
String from_date = request.getParameter("fromdate");
String to_date = request.getParameter("todate");
String document_level = request.getParameter("documentlevel");
String document_general = request.getParameter("documentgeneral");
String serial_number = request.getParameter("serialnumber");
String revision_number = request.getParameter("revisionnumber");
String iss_uer = request.getParameter("issuer");
String sta_tus = request.getParameter("status");
String file_Name = "";
String folder_Name = "allfiles";
String pa_th = folder_Name + File.separator + file_Name;
Timestamp add_ed_date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            
Connection con;
PreparedStatement ps;
ResultSet rs;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms","root","");
            
ps = con.prepareStatement("update dmsfiles set zid='"+z_id+"', firstname='"+first_Name+"',lastname='"+last_Name+"',mailid='"+mail_i_d+"',division='"+d_iv+"',department='"+de_pt+"',costcentercode='"+cost_centercode+"',document_number='"+doc_num+"',document_name='"+doc_Name+"',document_type='"+doc_Type+"',document_category='"+doc_Category+"',document_classification='"+doc_classification+"',authorised_by='"+authorised_by+"',fromdate='"+from_date+"',todate='"+to_date+"',document_level='"+document_level+"',document_general='"+document_general+"',serial_number='"+serial_number+"',revision_number='"+revision_number+"',issuer='"+iss_uer+"',status='"+sta_tus+"', filename='"+file_Name+"',path='"+pa_th+"',added_date='"+add_ed_date+"' where id = '"+id+"'");
            ps.setString(1, z_id);
            ps.setString(2,first_Name);
            ps.setString(3,last_Name);
            ps.setString(4,mail_i_d);
            ps.setString(5,d_iv);
            ps.setString(6,de_pt);
            ps.setString(7,cost_centercode);
            ps.setString(8,doc_num);
            ps.setString(9,doc_Name);
            ps.setString(10,doc_Type);
            ps.setString(11,doc_Category);
            ps.setString(12,doc_classification);
            ps.setString(13,authorised_by);
            ps.setString(14,from_date);
            ps.setString(15,to_date);
            ps.setString(16,document_level);
            ps.setString(17,document_general);
            ps.setString(18,serial_number);
            ps.setString(19,revision_number);
            ps.setString(20,iss_uer);
            ps.setString(21,sta_tus);
            ps.setString(22,file_Name);
            ps.setString(23,pa_th);
            ps.setTimestamp(24, add_ed_date);
            //ps.setString(25, id);
  
            ps.executeUpdate();
            con.close();   
%>
<script>
 alert("Record Updated!!");
</script> 
<%
}
catch(SQLException sql)
{
}
%>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Update record Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHide() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById("chk");
  var hiddeninputs = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");

   for (var i = 0; i != hiddeninputs.length; i++) {
      if (checkbox.checked) {
         hiddeninputs[i].style.display = "block";
      } else {
         hiddeninputs[i].style.display = "none";
      }
     }
   }
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    <div id="Registercontainer">
    <div class="RegForm">    
    <div id="back_glob">    
    <div id="back_form">
        <form action="success.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <%
                Connection con;
                PreparedStatement ps;
                ResultSet rs;
                
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms","root","");
                
                String id = request.getParameter("id");
                ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from dmsfiles where id = ?");
                ps.setString(1, id);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                
                while(rs.next()){


                
            %>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=rs.getString("id") %>"/>
        
            <center><h2>Update Record</h2></center>
            
            <table width="400px" align="center" border="2">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2">Form Details</td>
                </tr>
               <%-- <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="text" required="" name="zid" value="<%=rs.getString("id")%>"/></td>
                </tr> --%>
                <tr>
                    <td>Z id</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" required="" name="zid" value="<%=rs.getString("zid")%>"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" required="" name="firstname" value="<%=rs.getString("firstname")%>"/>
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" required="" name="lastname" value="<%=rs.getString("lastname")%>"/>
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mail id</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="email" required="" name="mailid" value="<%=rs.getString("mailid")%>"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Division</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="division" id="wgtmsr">
                    <option value="<%=rs.getString("division")%>"><%=rs.getString("division")%></option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="Z">Z</option>
                    <option value="I">I</option>
                    <option value="CF">CF</option>
                    <option value="P">P</option>
                    <option value="P">TT</option>
                    <option value="P">TC</option>
                    <option value="P">MA</option>
                    <option value="P">Z HYD</option>
                    <option value="P">CC</option>
                    <option value="P">CY</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
               <tr>
                    <td>Department</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="department" id="wgtmsr">
                    <option value="<%=rs.getString("department")%>"><%=rs.getString("department")%></option>
                    <option value="IT">IT</option>
                    <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
                    <option value="Logistics">Logistics</option>
                    <option value="Design">Design</option>
                    <option value="Purchase">Purchase</option>
                    <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
                    <option value="Material Management">Material Management</option>
                    
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>Cost Center Code</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="costcentercode" id="wgtmsr">
                    <option value="<%=rs.getString("costcentercode")%>"><%=rs.getString("costcentercode")%></option>
                    <option value="100115">100115</option>
                    <option value="100138">100138</option>
                    <option value="100630">100630</option>
                    <option value="100812">100812</option>
                    <option value="100823">100823</option>
                    <option value="500904">500904</option>
                    <option value="500907">500907</option>
                    <option value="700415">700415</option>
                    
                    
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Document Number</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" required="" name="documentnumber" value="<%=rs.getString("document_number")%>"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>Document Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" required="" name="documentname" value="<%=rs.getString("document_name")%>"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>Document Type</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="Document_Type" id="wgtmsr">
                    <option value="<%=rs.getString("document_type")%>"><%=rs.getString("document_type")%></option>
                    <option value="Agreement">Agreement</option>
                    <option value="Contract">Contract</option>
                    <option value="PO">PO</option>
                    <option value="Invoice">Invoice</option>
                    <option value="COA">COA</option>
                    <option value="Lease Deed">Lease Deed</option>
                    <option value="AMC">AMC</option>
                    <option value="Direct Material">Direct Material</option>
                    <option value="Indirect Material/Services">Indirect Material/Services</option>
                    
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <br><br>
                <tr>
                    <td>Document Category</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="Document_Category" id="wgtmsr">
                    <option value="<%=rs.getString("document_category")%>"><%=rs.getString("document_category")%></option>    
                    <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
                    <option value="Vendor">Vendor</option>
                    <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
                    
                    </select>
                    </td>
                
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Document Classification</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Document_Classification" id="wgtmsr">
                        <option value="<%=rs.getString("document_classification")%>"><%=rs.getString("document_classification")%></option>
                        <option value="Public">Public</option>
                        <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
                        <option value="ZF Confidential">ZF Confidential</option>
                        <option value="ZF Strictly Confidential">ZF Strictly Confidential</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                
                </tr>
                <br><br>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>Authorised By</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="authorisedby" id="wgtmsr">
                        <option value="<%=rs.getString("authorised_by")%>"><%=rs.getString("authorised_by")%></option>
                        <option value="Soma Ghosh">Soma Ghosh</option>
                        <option value="KV Suresh">KV Suresh</option>
                        <option value="Raghavendra Deolankar">Raghavendra Deolankar</option>
                        <option value="Shriram Aparnnaa">Shriram Aparnnaa</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>Validity - From date</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" required="" name="fromdate" value="<%=rs.getString("fromdate")%>"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Validity - To Date</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" required="" name="todate" value="<%=rs.getString("todate")%>"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                
                
                <!–– Code for QMS start   ––>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="chk">QMS</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk" value="check" onclick="showHide()"/>
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="hidden">Document Level(F31151)</label></td>
                    <td>
                        
                        <select name="documentlevel" class="hidden" id="wgtmsr">
                        <option value="<%=rs.getString("document_level")%>"><%=rs.getString("document_level")%></option>
                        <option value="0: QMM">0: QMM</option>
                        <option value="1: Business-Process">1: Business-Process</option>
                        <option value="2: Process & Descriptions">2: Process & Descriptions</option>
                        <option value="3: Work Instructions">Work Instructions</option>
                        <option value="4: Checklist & Form">Checklist & Form</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="hidden">Document 00 General</label></td>
                    <td>
                        
                        <select name="documentgeneral" class="hidden" id="wgtmsr">
                        <option value="<%=rs.getString("document_general")%>"><%=rs.getString("document_general")%></option>
                        <option value="00 General">00 General</option>
                        <option value="01 SDP Strategy Development Process">01 SDP Strategy Development Process</option>
                        <option value="02 Sales & Application Process">02 Sales & Application Process</option>
                        <option value="03 PDP Product Development Process">03 PDP Product Development Process</option>
                        <option value="04 PP Purchasing process">04 PP Purchasing process</option>
                        <option value="05 MP Maintenance Process">05 MP Maintenance Process</option>
                        <option value="06 Manufacturing & Delivery Process">06 Manufacturing & Delivery Process</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="hidden">Serial Number</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="serialnumber" class="hidden" value="<%=rs.getString("serial_number")%>"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="hidden">Revision No.</label></td>
                    <td >
                        
                        <select name="revisionnumber" class="hidden" id="wgtmsr">
                        <option value="<%=rs.getString("revision_number")%>"><%=rs.getString("revision_number")%></option>
                        <option value="00">00</option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>
                        <option value="03">03</option>
                        <option value="04">04</option>
                        <option value="05">05</option>
                        <option value="06">06</option>
                        <option value="07">07</option>
                        <option value="08">08</option>
                        <option value="09">09</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                
                
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="hidden">Issuer</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="issuer" class="hidden" value="<%=rs.getString("issuer")%>"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="hidden">Status</label></td>
                    <td>
                        
                        <select name="status" class="hidden" id="wgtmsr">
                        <option value="<%=rs.getString("status")%>"><%=rs.getString("status")%></option>
                        <option value="Public">Reserved</option>
                        <option value="Team">Implemented</option>
                        
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
  
                
                <!–– Code for QMS end   ––>
                <tr>
                    <td>Select File</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="fileName" multiple="multiple" value="<%=rs.getString("fileName")%>"/>
                        <span> <%=rs.getString("filename")%> </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
              <%  
                  }
              %>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                
            </table>
                <p><a href="home.jsp" class="btn btn-info">Back</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: This is my Database Screenshot]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212245/discussion-on-question-by-priya-dhanba-sql-update-query-trying-to-update-sql-r).

Answer (score 0):

It probably is due to,

```
  ps.setString(25, id);
```

You have total of 24 properties defined in the prepared statement that can be passed. However, You are passing 25 properties. Also, you should consider only updating the required necessary fields instead of updating all the parameters defined in the table.

Your statement looks like,

```
  ps = con.prepareStatement("update dmsfiles set zid=?, firstname=?,lastname=?,mailid=?,division=?,department=?,costcentercode=?,document_number=?,document_name=?,document_type=?,document_category=?,document_classification=?,authorised_by=?,fromdate=?,todate=?,document_level=?,document_general=?,serial_number=?,revision_number=?,issuer=?,status=?,filename=?,path=?,added_date=? where id = '"+id+"'");
```

Just replace,

```
where id = '"+id+"'")
```

with,

```
where id = ?")
```

Comment: I did changes as you said but not updated. when I clicked on submit button then same page opened.

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently have many errors , i cannot write all in comment thats the reason i am posting it as answer.Below are some errors i have seen in your code :

1.) You are passing all values in query directly i.e :`"update dmsfiles set zid='"+z_id+"', firstname='"+firstname...` and also you have use `ps.setString(..)` for all values ? why ?

2.) if your update code is on same page where is your form ? then ofcousre if you will put `<form action="success.jsp">` then your form will redirect to that page without submitting .Instead put your update code in `success.jsp` or use `response.sendRedirect()..` to redirect to `success.jsp` after updating.

3.) You have commented out `<input type="text" required="" name="zid" value="<%=rs.getString("id")%>"/>` in your `<form>` please uncomment this and change `name="id"` to get required `id` in your update code .

4.) Please print exception inside catch block i.e: `catch(SQLException sql){sql.printStackTrace();}` to see if your query has any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {    
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms","root","");

    ps = con.prepareStatement("update dmsfiles set zid=?, firstname=?,lastname=?,mailid=?,division=?,department=?,costcentercode=?,document_number=?,document_name=?,document_type=?,document_category=?,document_classification=?,authorised_by=?,fromdate=?,todate=?,document_level=?,document_general=?,serial_number=?,revision_number=?,issuer=?,status=?,filename=?,path=?,added_date=? where id = ?");

                ps.setString(1, z_id);
                ps.setString(2,first_Name);
                ps.setString(3,last_Name);
                ps.setString(4,mail_i_d);
                ps.setString(5,d_iv);
                ps.setString(6,de_pt);
                ps.setString(7,cost_centercode);
                ps.setString(8,doc_num);
                ps.setString(9,doc_Name);
                ps.setString(10,doc_Type);
                ps.setString(11,doc_Category);
                ps.setString(12,doc_classification);
                ps.setString(13,authorised_by);
                ps.setString(14,from_date);
                ps.setString(15,to_date);
                ps.setString(16,document_level);
                ps.setString(17,document_general);
                ps.setString(18,serial_number);
                ps.setString(19,revision_number);
                ps.setString(20,iss_uer);
                ps.setString(21,sta_tus);
                ps.setString(22,file_Name);
                ps.setString(23,pa_th);
                ps.setTimestamp(24, add_ed_date);
                ps.setString(25, id); //<- uncommented this

                ps.executeUpdate();

                ps.close(); //<- added this
                con.close();   
} catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("Error: " + e.toString()); // If error occured, you can see the error message in detail
        }
```

Comment: can you please help me how can write or use update query in my  above UploadServletClass.java file.

Comment: If I do comment for this line `ps.setString(25, id);`  then I got this error `Error: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 25`

Comment: I got this error on web page. `Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'zid' cannot be null`, when I did uncomment `ps.setString(25, id);`

Comment: @priyadhanba your all db fields are 'not-null', so you can't set the null in the table. Please check the nullable of all fields before the db conection.

Comment: @priyadhanba And you write this - <a href="update.jsp?id=<%=id%>" ,  so in update.jsp, all other paramters perhaps will be the null, except id paramter.

Comment: can you please tell me what changes I should  do in code?

Comment: @priyadhanba your db updating code will be moved to success.jsp from update.jsp

Comment: I have only this line in success.jsp page `<body>
        <h1>record updated successfully</h1>
        <a href="home.jsp">Click here to go home</a>
    </body>`

Comment: In your code, updated data was made in update.jsp and submit the data to success.jsp. So, you can get the inputed data in success.jsp only.